# I am getting an error while trying to build a component which accept generic classes and styles with [ngClass] and [ngStyles]

Tags: angular

I am creating an Angular library in which users can pass in their custom styles and classes to the component in the library via [ngClass] or [ngStyle], a snippet of the code goes like this:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `<button [ngClass]="class" [ngStyle]="style" 
  (click)="pay()">Init App</button>`,
})
```

my problem occurs anytime I try to build the library, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: projects/button-widget/src/lib/button-widget.component.ts.buttonWidgetComponent.html(1,9): Property 'style' does not exist on type 'ButtonWidgetComponent'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are class and style?

Answer (score 0):

ngClass takes strings, arrays or objects and ngStyle requires key-value pairs, like

```
[ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}"
```

If indeed your class and style properties contain such objects, I would suggest renaming those properties.

Property binding for your case:

In the HTML where the user wants to use your component:

```
<button-widget [dynamicClass]="classVar" [dynamicStyle]="styleVar" ><button-widget>
```

If nothing is passed the defaults will be used.
In the button component.ts:

```
@Input() dynamicClass = {some default};
@Input() dynamicStyle = {some default};
```

In the button template rename class and style to dynamicClass and dynamicStyle, ofcourse the names are up to you.

Comment: I am trying to create placeholders so that in the user of my library can style or give it a class.

Comment: what do you mean when you say library?

Comment: a reusable angular module people can use in their own app.

Comment: okay, so the class and style will be passed using property binding? If so assign a default object to those variables and if the user passes a style and class it'll get replaced.

Comment: @Ramesh...yes yes. But it seems like I am not doing the property binding well

Comment: I edited my answer, make sure you're using property binding as such.